# why the following code upon executing in python gives <type ‘generator’> type?

Tags: python

Why the following code upon executing in python gives ‘generator’ type?

```
dic= ((I, (I**3)) for I in range(25))

print type(dic)
```

output:

can someone explains me ?

Comment: check your brackets, that's why, what happens when you use `[,]` instead of `(,)`

Comment: Why did you expect anything else?

Comment: Because you created a generator, what did you expect?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy the variable name suggests the were expecting a `dict` anyways.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy you have that the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting type is defined by surrounding brackets:

```
>>> dic = ((I, (I**3)) for I in range(25))
>>> type(dic)
<class 'generator'>

>>> dic = [(I, (I**3)) for I in range(25)]
>>> type(dic)
<class 'list'>

>>> dic = {I: (I**3) for I in range(25)}
>>> type(dic)
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: thank you, that was simple and fantastic explanation maurice, :) thumbsup, it cleared my doubt

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to generate a large number of data but you only need one at a time then you can use generator, as you have in your code

```
dic= ((I, (I**3)) for I in range(25))
# type of dic is a generator
```

But if you want an in memory all data in form of list then instead of using prenthesis, use brackets.

```
dic= [(I, (I**3)) for I in range(25)]
# type of dic is list
```

> Result: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 8), (3, 27), (4, 64), (5, 125), (6, 216), (7, 343), (8, 512), (9, 729), (10, 1000), (11, 1331), (12, 1728), (13, 2197), (14, 2744), (15, 3375), (16, 4096), (17, 4913), (18, 5832), (19, 6859), (20, 8000), (21, 9261), (22, 10648), (23, 12167), (24, 13824)]